# Which port should I select for "add a predefined host"?

Tags: resilio-sync

I have installed BT Sync on my linux server, I can access my BT sync via http://myip:8888
and I have set the Listening port of my BT sync is 26131 
[image]

**A:** I hope to set "Add new host" in my mobile iphone BT sync, which port should I set for the predefind host, 8888 or 26131 ?

[image]

And more, from the artical https://help.getsync.com/hc/en-us/articles/212016726-Sync-Interface-on-iOS-devices

**B:** it seems that the predefined host are avaiable only when relay, tracker and  search LAN options are set to OFF, right?
Does it mean that the predefined host will not work if I set search LAN options to ON?

**C:** And more, the predefined host is only available for BT sync software in PC client, right ?  and  the predefined host  don't work for BT sync  App in iPhone ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Sync expert so I can only answer from my own experience, but here goes:

**A:** That should be 26131. The 8888 port is just for the management interface.

**B:** I cannot confirm for Linux or iPhone, but on the platforms I am using (Windows, Android) you can mix both. I leave those options ON, but have also specified some predefined hosts to make things work at a couple of locations where the search does not work because of firewall issues. It is not required to turn it OFF to make it work.

**C:** Again, I don't know about iPhone -- on Android it is available, *but* only for "advanced" folders, not for "standard" folders. So if you are missing it on mobile, it may be because it's a standard folder, not because you're on iPhone.